# Android: NullPointerException when calling EditText getText() method

Tags: java, android, xml

I've recently updated my eclipse ADT and now when I start new activities I have mutch more methods implemented in the correspondig class and I'm not sure if the way I should connect my variables to the corresponding views has changed.. anyway, I'm doing it this way:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText editTextNumeroCartao,
         editTextPassword;

InternetConnectivityManager icm;

ProgressDialog pDialog;
UserFunctions userFunction;
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    // conecta as variáveis ás respectivas views
    editTextNumeroCartao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumeroCartao);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    icm = new InternetConnectivityManager(getApplicationContext());
}
```

But when I try to get the text inside this EditText's I get Null Pointer Exception...

```
public void doLogin(View view) {

    if(icm.isOnline()) {

        String numeroCartao = this.editTextNumeroCartao.getText().toString();
        String password = this.editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        if(numeroCartao == null || numeroCartao.trim().equals("") || password == null || password.trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insere todos os dados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            new LoginAsyncTask().execute(numeroCartao, password);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não estás ligado à Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return;
}
```

My activity_login xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="me.pap.bruno.esdahconnect.LoginActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

My fragment_login xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="me.pap.bruno.esdahconnect.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Número do Cartão"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumeroCartao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Entrar" 
    android:onClick="doLogin" />
```

Can somebody help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: show activity_login.xml

Comment: where do you call the doLogin from?

Comment: I call it with the android:onClick="doLogin" in my xml fragment file

Comment: I recently attempted to post a canonical reference to probelms like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`editTextNumeroCartao` and `editTextPassword` are in `fragment_login.xml` but you are using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`.

That's the reason it is giving you a `NullPointerException` because the mentioned `EditText` can not be found in the XML.

Either change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);`

or

move the `EditText` code to your `Fragment`

Comment: you're right.. with this new changes I end up with this 2 layouts and I didn't really knew which to change.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You've your both editText declared in fragment layout but in your code you are accessing through activity_man.xml.

Either change this to Fragement layout or move the edittext related code to the Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you trying:

```
editTextNumeroCartao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumeroCartao);
editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
```

in your Activity, but this elements are in Fragment. I think there is the reason that they are null